# Which version of boost should I use with c++ visual-studio-2005?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, boost, visual-c++-2005

Does anyone know what version of the Boost Library to use with Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest version, [1.41.0](http://www.boost.org/users/news/version_1_41_0).

If you're interested, Boost maintains [a page with the current status of the regression tests on a variety of platforms](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/release/developer/summary.html), including Visual C++ 7.1, 8.0, and 9.0 (Visual Studio 2003, 2005, and 2008, respectively).

Comment: If you're looking for the latest binaries, you can get them here: http://boost.teeks99.com

Answer (score 1):

I have been using 1.36 for a while, and it works great. I tried 1.39 for a bit and also works good.

I find it much easier to install the package from [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download), since they package it specifically for various Visual Studio versions, and allow for a customized install to let you choose just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1.33.1 and 1.39.0 work with no problems in VS2K5 here at work..